# Unable to get value of the property 'content': object is null or undefined

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I get this error every time i compile my PhoneGap 2.9.0 project. I copied "www" folder into my Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Codrova Project because iw anted to test the program on WP 7(I've already tested it on Android and iOS emulators and devices).

```
Error:["Unable to get value of the property 'content': object is null or undefined file:x-wmapp1:\/app\/www\/index.html Line:1","DebugConsole380383071"]
```

As far as i've found out, this bug is fixed only if i delete cordova.js include in my index.html file. I'm hoping that fixing this bag will solve the problem of file downloading in my program, because it's not working in WP 7 now. Here is the function for file downloading:

```
    function fileDownload(fileName, finalName) {
        window.requestFileSystem(
                     LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
                     function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
                     fileSystem.root.getFile(
                                 "dummy.html", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
                                 function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
                                 var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.html","") + "Appname/Cachefolded";
                                 var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                                 fileEntry.remove();                                             
                                 fileTransfer.download(
                                           finalName,
                                           sPath + finalName,
                                           function(theFile) {},
                                           function(error) {}
                                           );
                                 }, 
                                 null);
                     }, 
                     null
        );
};
```

In addition, i'm using few PhoneGap API's:
* Device
* Connection
* FileSystem
* LocalStorage

Data is downloaded via Ajax like this:

```
        $.ajax({
                url: base + "user.php?imei=" + imei,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    fileDownload(data.img, "avatar.jpg");
                }
            });
```

I'll publish all nessesary code if you are interested in a specific part. Don't wanna post it here to keep my question readable. Thanks for any help in advance.

P.S. Line 1 of the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I've the same problem. Still looking for solution

Comment: @ozeczek It's sad, but the only thing I can say is that I haven't found any solution so far so I gave up trying to run my application on WP7.

Comment: I dont have excuse, just have to make it work. When I also remove cordova.js its working. I have facilitation because my app will start and its workin even with that error.